# How to share virtual GPIO data between guest and host system in qemu 7.1.0

Tags: linux, virtualization, qemu, gpio, robotics

I want to create a virtual raspberry pi machine inside qemu version 7.1.0. I then want to share data between the virtual raspberry pi guest system and my host system. Looking at the qemu documentation, I *think* that the [Inter-VM Shared Memory Device](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/devices/ivshmem.html?highlight=ivshmem) is what I want.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://blog.ramdoot.in/emulating-raspberry-pi-on-with-qemu-951283daf2bd) such that the following command allows me to properly boot up a raspberry pi virtual machine:

`qemu-system-aarch64 -M raspi3b -display none -append "rw earlyprintk loglevel=8 console=ttyAMA0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootdelay=1" -dtb ./dtbs/bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb -sd raspios.qcow -kernel kernel8.img -m 1G -smp 4 -serial mon:stdio -usb -device usb-mouse -device usb-kbd -device usb-net,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22`

So far so good. Now, when I add the following flags to the command above for including the Ivshmem device like so:

`-object memory-backend-file,size=1M,share=on,mem-path=/dev/shm/ivshmem,id=hostmem -device ivshmem-plain,memdev=hostme`

I get the following error:

`-device ivshmem-plain,memdev=hostmem: No 'PCI' bus found for device 'ivshmem-plain'`

Apparently arm devices don't have PCI buses. But according to [this article](http://maquefel.me/en/qemu-ivshmem-introducing-interrupt-capable-virtual-gpio-concept/) someone does use the ivshmem device successfully on an ARM-based *versatilepb* system. That article, by the way, looks exactly like what I'm trying to do on my system, but it also appears to be quite old, and if I try to follow the commands verbatim, I run into issues and errors left and right.

Is it possible to use the ivshmem inter-vm shared memory device to set up a shared memory region between my host x86_64 system and a guest raspberry pi 3b embedded board?

If it is possible, then I suspect that it's just an issue of finding the right flags.

I'm very new to embedded systems and the qemu documentation is dense and immense, and I'm not sure if this is even the right direction to take.

I'm trying to connect the two systems because I want a program on my host system to be able to send input to and receive output from the virtual raspberry pi's gpio pins. Any help and/or other ways of doing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether there is a PCI bus or not does not depend on the guest CPU architecture (arm, x86, etc), but on the guest machine type. Some Arm boards have PCI buses, and some don't. In theory you could have an x86 machine with no PCI bus. Specifically, the 'versatilepb' machine happens to have a PCI bus. This is because we're modelling real hardware, and that particular bit of real hardware had PCI slots you could plug PCI devices into.

The raspberry PI real hardware doesn't have a PCI bus, and so QEMU's model of it also does not have PCI. The result is that you can't use the ivshmem device on that board type.

I'm not sure that the ivshmem device would help you in doing anything with the emulated GPIO pins anyway, though. QEMU's model of GPIO does not currently include modelling the ability to connect those pins to anything -- we just model the GPIO controller hardware so that the guest doesn't get confused, but it acts like there's nothing plugged into those pins.